# button on homescreen widget

Tags: android, widget

I have an widget with an button (R.id.button) 
When I click the button, it should open the activity: "openactivity" 
Do you now I can do this. It's an basic question because I'm new in Android developing.

I hope you understand me, and you could help me.

Gaauwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a PendingIntent, as described in the the android docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider